# How to define aliases with Ariadne's set_alias?

Tags: ariadne-graphql

According to the [Ariadne's documentation](https://ariadnegraphql.org/docs/resolvers#aliases), it should be possible to define field aliases with `set_alias`. But I can't make it work, `set_alias` does not complain but any query for the alias field returns null.

```
# test.py 
from ariadne import ObjectType, gql, make_executable_schema
from ariadne.asgi import GraphQL
from types import SimpleNamespace

type_defs = gql("""
    type Query {
        hello: String!
        goodbye: String!
    }
""")

query = ObjectType("Query")

@query.field("hello")
def resolve_hello(_, info):
    request = info.context['request']
    user_agent = request.headers.get('user-agent', 'guest')
    return 'hello, %s' % user_agent

query.set_alias('goodbye', 'hello')

schema = make_executable_schema(type_defs, query )

app = GraphQL(schema, debug=True)
```

which I run with `uvicorn test:app`

So what is the proper way to define an alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what `set_alias` do. `set_alias` can only alias an existing **attribute** (not resolver) in the resolved object. So let say that you have a field `user` that resolves to an object with attributes `first_name` and `last_name` you can define an alias `first` that maps to `first_name`. So in essence `set_alias` gives you a convenient syntax to define resolvers that map to an object's attribute:

```
from ariadne import QueryType, ObjectType, gql, make_executable_schema
from ariadne.asgi import GraphQL
from types import SimpleNamespace

type_defs = gql("""
    type Query {
        user: User
    }

    type User {
        username: String!
        first: String
        last: String
    }
""")

query = QueryType()


@query.field("user")
def resolve_user(obj, info):
    to_return = SimpleNamespace()
    to_return.first_name = 'Rubén'
    to_return.last_name = 'Laguna'
    return to_return

user = ObjectType("User")

@user.field("username")
def resolve_username(obj, info):
    return f"{obj.first_name} {obj.last_name}"


user.set_alias('last', 'last_name')
user.set_alias('first', 'first_name')

schema = make_executable_schema(type_defs, query, user)

app = GraphQL(schema, debug=True)
```

A query for `{user { first}}`  will return `{"data": {"user": {"first": "Rubén"}}}` without having to provide a full fledge resolver for `first`.